# Retrieving info from a database in C# with SQL commands

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access

I'm currently trying to make a book manager in C#. I'm using a `.ACCDB` Database to store data about the books.

First I retrieve the `bookIDs` that belong to a specific series with:

```
sql.CommandText = "select * from BookTable where SeriesID = " +
DataClass.SeriesTableIndex;
```

It retrieves the `BookIDs` `20` and `23`. These are the correct `BookIDs` corresponding to the `SeriesID` in the DB.

After this my code builds the next sql command.
I left out the functional building of the command.
It builds the following code:

```
string sqlcommand = "select * from BookTable where BookID = 23 or 20"
```

I use this command to get the book names:

```
sql.CommandText = sqlcommand;
```

It should only return `bookWithID23` and `bookWithID20` but it also returns `bookWithID21`. There are only 3 books in my testing DB but it somehow returns all 3 instead of the 2 in the series.

I don't really know anything about SQL so it's probably a simple syntax error.

Comment: BookID = 23 or 20 is always true since 'or 20' is a constant which always evaluates to true hence this is why you get all records in your table. You should write as suggested by @S.Akbari. This behaviour is not unique to SQL

Comment: It makes no sense to execute 2 queries. The first one already returns all the columns of the books you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax of `or` is (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp):

```
"BookID = 23 or BookID = 20"
```

Also you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), something like this:

```
sql.CommandText = "select * from BookTable where SeriesID = @SeriesID";
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeriesID", DataClass.SeriesTableIndex);
```

Although specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`:

```
sql.Parameters.Add("@SeriesID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DataClass.SeriesTableIndex;
```

[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)